# CNAME and Nginx

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, reverse-proxy

Let say I have such kind of record in my `extdomain.com`:

```
extdomain.com         CNAME    abc.newdomain.com
www.extdomain.com     CNAME    abc.newdomain.com
```

And I'd like to use nginx proxy_pass to use but basing on **TO** domain

```
server_name ~^(.*)\.newdomain\.com$;
set $sub $1;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://other_server/$sub;
}
```

Now when user visits `www.extdomain.com` I should have a `server_name` which will match this domain. Is there an option to use **TO** domain instead of **FROM**? Can we use somehow resolver to not play with vhost for adding each new domain?

Comment: No. Only the client's browser is concerned with the CNAME when it is trying to resolve the IP address of the server. The server only sees the `Host` header with a value of `www.extdomain.com`.

Comment: @RichardSmith so there's no record which works like `CNAME` but can send `abc.newdomain.com` too? so bad.

Comment: By record, you mean a DNS record? Nginx is an HTTP server and not a DNS server. What the client sends to Nginx is determined by HTTP and not DNS. Some DNS providers have a web forwarding option, but I don't know how it works. If you have a Nginx server, you could set up your own reverse proxy, but it would not automatically sync with the CNAME records on your DNS server, unless you write it yourself.

Comment: @RichardSmith I saw this solution working on some hosting services, that's why I'm wondering how it works exactly.